# Sending multilingual email. Which charset should I suse?

Tags: email, character-encoding, special-characters

I want to send emails in a number of languages (en/es/fr/de/ru/pl). I notice that Gmail uses KOI8-R charset when sending emails contatining Cyrillic characters.

Can I just use KOI8-R for ALL my emails, or is there any reason to select a particular charset for each language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would recommend alway using utf-8 nowadays.

wikipedia on utf-8:

> UTF-8 (8-bit UCS/Unicode
>   Transformation Format) is a
>   variable-length character encoding for
>   Unicode. It is able to represent any
>   character in the Unicode standard, yet
>   is backwards compatible with ASCII.
>   For these reasons, it is steadily
>   becoming the preferred encoding for
>   e-mail, web pages,[1] and other places
>   where characters are stored or
>   streamed.

Answer (score 2):

Use UTF-8. KOI8-R wouldn't be ideal for non-Russian languages, and changing codesets always tends to be a headache on the receiving side.